# Constrain image in responsive div (Bootstrap 4)

Tags: css, image, bootstrap-4, responsive

I have a  that is changing in width (col-x) and in height (h-100) depending on the browser window. Inside that div is a very large image being displayed. The problem with .img-fluid is that it is only constraining in width, depending on the container. But I need a solution that also scales height, when the size of the container div shrinks. But I have not found a solution.

I tried different combinations of min-height, max-height, object-fit and so on, but always the image does not shrink in width, when the container gets smaller (or then when the proportions of the div change from portrait to landscape it does not follow.

I tried to build a basic plunker to demonstrate using vh for the height of the wrapper. So the goal would be for both images to always stay inside the column. You can try playing around with the height and width of the browser to see the effect.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col-4">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OrtT.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OrtT.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
    </div>        
  </div>
</div>
```

Styles:

```
.wrapper {
  height: 60vh; 
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/LbavqYXNNVlftUOw4Xfr?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Add css height:100%; for image